# Shorter distance between $x^2$ and $x-2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I've been trying to solve this problem by using the Lagrangian multiplier method, but I get lost somewhere. My reasoning is the following:

There must be a point $(a,a^2)$ somewhere in the parabola which is as close as you can get to some point $(b,b-4)$ (a point in the line). The distance between those two generic points is the module of the vector $(a-b,a^2-b+4)$. So let there $f(a,b)$ be the function that I'll call *distance squared* (to simplify the calculations):

$$f(a,b)=(a-b)^2+(a^2-b+4)^2$$

Now, my question is: what are the constrictions we should use to find the shortest distance? I solved this problem without using this method, but the process involved a third grade polynomial that I couldn't solve without using a computer/calculator, so I don't want to rely on that.

How should one proceed? I don't want anyone to solve my problem, of course, I just need a guideline on what to do now. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Lagrange-multipliers are for implementing constraints in an optimization problem. But after you parameterized the points as $(a,a^2)$ and $(b,b-4)$, there are no further constraints. I don't see a useful way to involve Lagrange here.

Comment: Apparently a classmate asked the professor the right way to do this and he said that we should (somehow) use Lagrange. This classmate defined a Lagrangian function consisting on the one I typed, plus $\lambda$ multiplying $x-2$ and $\mu$ multiplying $x^2$. I just don't see why he did that. (He then needed to solve a 6x6 equation system and use Weierstrass' theorem, which sounds unnecessarily complex for a problem like this).

Comment: Well, you can parameterize the two points as $(a_1,a_2)$ and $(b_1,b_2)$ and then use the constraints $a_1^2-a_2=0$ and $b_1-b_2-2=0$. Then you have simpler equations, but more of them.

Comment: Yes, Lagrange's Multipliers can indeed be used with two phony variables $\;\lambda,\,\mu\;$ ....but in this case that'd be way too cumbersome and overkill. I show you a way to reduce that to one phony variable and then differentiating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, write the line in standard form:

$$y=x-2\implies x-y-2=0$$

Now, take a generic point on the parabola: $\;(a,a^2)\;$ , and now evaluate the distance from this point to the line:

$$d(a):=\frac{|a-a^2-2|}{\sqrt{1^2+(-1)^2}}=\frac{|a-a^2-2|}{\sqrt2}$$

(Observe that by geometric considerations (i.e. looking at the graphs), we could already assume $\;a\ge0\;$), and then do some differential calculus:

$$d'(a)=\pm\frac{1-2a}{\sqrt2}=0\iff a=\frac12$$

and the minimal distance is thus

$$d\left(\frac12\right)=\frac{\left|\frac12-\frac14-2\right|}{\sqrt2}=\frac7{4\sqrt2}$$

**Another way**: we want to minimize the (square of the) distance $\;D(x,y):+(a-x)^2+(a^2-y)^2\;$ from a generic point $\;(a,a^2)\;$ on the parabola, under the restriction that $\;y=x-2\iff x-y-2=0\;$ , so

$$H_\lambda=(a-x)^2+(a^2-y)^2+\lambda(x-y-2)\implies$$$${}$$

$$\begin{cases}&I\;\;&H'_x=-2(a-x)+\lambda=0\iff\lambda=2(a-x)\\{}\\
&II\;\;&H'_y=-2(a^2-y)-\lambda=0\iff\lambda=-2(a^2-y)\\{}\\
&III\;\;&H'_\lambda=x-y-2=0\iff y=x-2\end{cases}$$

From I - II - III above,  we get

$$\begin{cases}&I\;\;&x=a-\frac\lambda2\\{}\\
&II\;\;&y=a^2+\frac\lambda2\\{}\\&III\;\;&a^2+\frac\lambda2=a-\frac\lambda2-2\end{cases}\;\;\;\;\;\;\stackrel{III}\implies\;\;\lambda=a-a^2-2$$

and from here:

$$I\;\;x=a-\frac{a-a^2-2}2=\frac{a+a^2}2+1\;,\;\;II\;\;y=a^2+\frac{a-a^2-2}2=\frac{a+a^2}2-1$$

and

$$D\left(\frac{a+a^2}2+1\,,\,\,\frac{a+a^2}2-1\right)=\left(\frac{a-a^2}2-1\right)^2+\left(\frac{a^2-a}2+1\right)^2\implies$$

$$D'(a)=(1-2a)\left(\frac{a-a^2}2-1\right)+(2a-1)\left(\frac{a-a^2}2+1\right)\stackrel ?=0\implies$$

$$(2a-1)\cdot2=0\implies a=\frac12$$

and we get again the same as before.

Comment: Could you explain the part about evaluating the distance from the point to the line?

Comment: @Manuel That is a very well known formula from analytic geometry. You can check it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line  , or also here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. I think that's the method our professor wanted us to use ('using the Lagrangian multiplier method'), and it's a lot simpler than what my classmate did. I understood it, you've been really helpful. I didn't know the formula, so thanks for the links too :)

Comment: An easier way to obtain $a=1/2$ is to notice that the tangent line in the point of the closest distance must be parallel to $x-2$, hence $2a=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Use
$$x^2+y^2\ge\frac{(x+y)^2}2$$

Let $f(a;b)=(a-b)^2+(a^2-b+2)^2$

Then 
$$(a-b)^2+(a^2-b+2)^2=(a-b)^2+(-a^2+b-2)^2\ge\frac{(a-b-a^2+b-2)^2}{2}=$$
$$=\frac{(a^2-a+2)^2}{2}=\frac{((a-\frac12)^2+\frac{7}4)^2}{2}\ge\frac{49}{32}$$

Hence, shorter distance between $x^2$ and $x−2$ is $$\frac{7}{4\sqrt2}$$

Comment: I don't understand what you did. Could you explain? I would theoretically need the points that make for the shorter distance (which I forgot to mention, my bad).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :)